# Recursive regular expressions for defining syntax using 'fr' strings

Tags: python, regex, syntax, bnf, f-string

When creating grammar rules for a language I am making, I would like to be able to check syntax and step through it instead of the current method which often will miss syntax errors.

I've started off using regular expressions to define the grammar like so:

```py
add = r"(\+)"
sub = r"(-)"
mul = r"(\*)"
div = r"(\\)"
pow = r"(\^)"
bin_op = fr"({add}|{sub}|{mul}|{div}|{pow})"

open_br = r"(\()"
close_br = r"(\))"
open_sq = r"(\[)"
close_sq = r"(\])"

dot = r"(\.)"

short_id = r"([A-Za-z]\d*)" # i.e. "a1", "b1232", etc.
long_id = r"([A-Za-z0-9]+)" # i.e. "sin2", "tan", etc. for use in assignment
long_id_ref = r"('" + long_id + "')" # i.e. "'sin'", for referencing
#note that "'sin'" is one value while "sin" = "s" * "i" * "n"
id_assign = fr"({short_id}|{long_id})" # for assignment
id_ref = fr"({short_id}|{long_id_ref})" # for reference (apostrophes)

integer = r"(\d+)" # i.e 123
float = fr"(\d+{dot}\d+)" # i.e. 3.4
operand = fr"({integer}|{float}|{id_ref})"
```

Now the issue here is that definitions may be recursive, for example in `expression = fr"{expression}{bin_op}{expression}|({open_br}{expression}{close_br})|({expression}{open_sq}{expression}{close_sq})|..."` and as you can see, I have shown some possible expressions that would be recursive. The issue is, of course, that `expression` is not defined when defining `expression` therefore an error would be raised.
It seems that `(?R)` would not work since it would copy everything before it not the whole string. Does Python's regex have a way of dealing with this or do I have to create my own BNF or regex interpreter that supports recursion?
Alternatively would it be feasible to use regular expressions but not use any recursion?

I know that there are 3rd-party applications that can help with this but I'd like to be able to do it all myself without external code.

Comment: If you have a recursively defined grammar, I'd think it'd be best to write a parser (assuming you aren't interested in using Lark or something like that). Regex is pretty limited for general parsing.

Comment: I agree with @ggorlen entirely. Regex is the wrong tool for the task, unfortunately.

Comment: `(?R)` and it's derivatives should be available in the Python replacement regex engine, simply called `import regex` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/